# Linux netfilter / iptables : How to enable iptables TRACE chain handling with nf_log_syslog on RHEL8+?

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables, netfilter, nftables

On a Linux RHEL8 system, I have enabled these iptables rules ,
which I am led to believe should enable ICMP packet syslog logging
on interface ingress & egress :

```
# iptables -L -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TRACE      icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TRACE      icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
```

As described at : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2313671
I have done :

```
# modprobe  nf_log_ipv4
# sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4
```

I also did:

```
# modprobe nf_log_syslog
```

which I am led to believe replaces all previous nf_log* or ipt_LOG modules
in modern (RHEL8 4.18.x) kernels.

But, when I 'ping' a NAT'd (with iptables) IP address, no TRACE log messages
appear in 'dmesg -c' output or in syslog (systemd.journald in use).

What am I missing ? Much thanks for any informative replies.

The most comprehensive discussion I have found on this issue
so far on the web is at :

https://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/
(thanks waldner!)

But this is getting rather old (2010-06-11) , and evidently
does not apply to kernel 4.18(RHEL) .

I have duplicated precisely the steps above on Fedora-36
(kernel-6.2.16) system , and it DOES work, TRACE log messages
ARE generated :

```
# iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j TRACE
# iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j TRACE
# modprobe nf_log_ipv4
# echo nf_log_ipv4 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log/2
```

But, these steps, when repeated on a RHEL8 kernel 4.18.0-477.13.1 host,
do not work / produce any packet TRACE output in logs - this is what
I am tearing what remains of my hair out trying to resolve.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Comment: Note that [firewall questions are also off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firewall/info)

Answer (score 0):

Redhat migrated to nftable since RHEL8. Even though `iptables` command should still works on RHEL8 and translates rules to nftable format, you can try to use native `nft` command to create the rules.

Here are some more details
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/08/18/iptables-the-two-variants-and-their-relationship-with-nftables#